# Is there a way to make ggplot follow a specific route when adding new data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I think this question has been asked by someone but I couldn't find an answer for my data. I have two data sets, data1 and data2. data1 should be the points and data2 should be a line goes on top of it. However, ggplot (in my case) did not take into consideration 2 possible points on y for each x point.

```
    data1<- structure(list(Total.VolumeD = c(86.8, 74.4, 110.8, 80.4, 118, 
81.2, 48.4, 109.6, 59.2, 22.8, 65.6, 72.4, 89.2, 140.8, 100, 
95.6, 66.8, 119.6, 74.8, 100, 86.4, 77.6, 76.8, 72.8, 42, 54.8, 
54.4, 60.8, 32.8, 96.4, 144, 146.4, 82.4, 98, 96.4, 84, 78.8, 
94, 102.4, 88.4, 105.2, 81.2, 54, 74.4, 54, 130, 64.8, 86.8, 
29.6, 76.4, 88.8, 64, 131.6, 84.4, 76.8, 64.4, 57.6, 62.4, 75.2, 
78.4, 53.2, 105.2, 62, 90.8, 98, 94.8, 66, 107.2, 98.8, 105.2, 
106.4, 93.6, 65.2, 70, 102, 64.8, 30, 69.6, 141.2, 67.2, 84.8, 
36.4, 35.2, 68.4, 70, 66.4, 53.2, 81.6, 32, 66, 54, 62.4, 59.2, 
82.8, 119.6, 112, 57.6, 92.4, 40.4, 21.2), Speed_KM = c(43.443, 
112.63, 59.533, 109.412, 57.924, 45.052, 106.194, 112.63, 107.803, 
98.149, 109.412, 112.63, 107.803, 107.803, 51.488, 107.803, 109.412, 
35.398, 112.63, 107.803, 109.412, 109.412, 112.63, 109.412, 109.412, 
111.021, 111.021, 104.585, 106.194, 111.021, 57.924, 109.412, 
109.412, 107.803, 106.194, 109.412, 109.412, 112.63, 46.661, 
106.194, 112.63, 109.412, 114.239, 104.585, 107.803, 54.706, 
111.021, 109.412, 109.412, 99.758, 54.706, 114.239, 82.059, 106.194, 
112.63, 107.803, 114.239, 111.021, 107.803, 112.63, 102.976, 
111.021, 111.021, 112.63, 112.63, 109.412, 114.239, 59.533, 112.63, 
109.412, 112.63, 111.021, 111.021, 111.021, 109.412, 107.803, 
109.412, 94.931, 48.27, 109.412, 111.021, 109.412, 107.803, 111.021, 
114.239, 114.239, 109.412, 109.412, 106.194, 111.021, 109.412, 
112.63, 114.239, 112.63, 107.803, 69.187, 109.412, 111.021, 111.021, 
102.976)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the second dataset is:

```
data2<- structure(list(q = c(158.4, 274.133, 414.102, 613.637, 787.081, 
899.571, 1020.936, 1134.581, 1282.396, 1424.662, 1571.935, 1741.292, 
1549.867, 1488.96, 1514.317, 1519.543, 1574.4, 1456.615, 1470.912, 
1481.04, 1419.443, 1452.916, 1423.418, 1382.8, 1367.611, 1369.1, 
1341.45, 1329.36, 1243.765, 1257.6, 1141.371, 1076.16, 1100, 
1142.4, 895.2, 1468.8, 854.4, 796.8, 662.4, 1070.4), u = c(91.11, 
103.713, 106.808, 110.56, 111.033, 109.907, 109.392, 109.494, 
108.584, 107.729, 105.759, 101.676, 88.793, 83.024, 81.726, 76.313, 
72.904, 67.578, 66.677, 62.912, 59.183, 58.509, 56.656, 53.734, 
50.401, 49.007, 48.32, 45.776, 43.632, 43.736, 42.064, 45.696, 
35.934, 32.18, 23.331, 36.202, 45.052, 77.232, 53.097, 62.751
)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: this picture shows what I want. Instead of the read dots, I want a smooth line.]

I have tried the following code:

```
data1%>%
  ggplot(aes( x = Total.VolumeD,y = Speed_KM, width = 0.5)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.5, color = "grey")+
  geom_smooth(data = data2, aes(x = q, y =u , size = 5, color = "red"))
```

My result should be something like the picture below without the red points.
[image: The result]

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue when I copy/paste the code you provided. But perhaps it's a problem with specifying the aesthetics in the wrong place. What if you try `ggplot(data1) + geom_point(aes( x = Total.VolumeD,y = Speed_KM, width = 0.5), size = 1.5, color = "grey")+ geom_smooth(data = data2, aes(x = q, y =u , size = 5),  color = "red")`

Comment: The data sets are very big and cannot share them on stackoverflow. I used the same code and it is not solving the problem. I need data2 to be plotted as a smooth line on top of data1. @MrFlick

Comment: When you use the sample data you provide here, does it look correct? I see a smooth line when I run the code. If we can't replicate the problem it's very difficult to help you. There may be something weird going on in your R workspace so restarting R may help.

Comment: I am sharing the right sample. I restated R and it still showing the error. Is there a way to share my entire data set with you? @MrFlick

Comment: The blue line you've added cannot be done with geom_smooth because that only draws proper functions (a function will not have two y values for the same x). Instead maybe you want the `ggalt::geom_xspline` function. But that still doesn't explain why you are getting points. I'm not interested in getting your full data. If you can't post a reproducible example in the question itself, then I really can't help any further.

Comment: I am updating the question with a bigger portion of my dataset. I hope that helps. Thanks @MrFlick

Comment: I DONOT need the red big points. I need something like the blue line instead. I hope that the question is clear and if it is not please let me know to update it.